# What is Engine.mc() and why is it slowing down my model?

Tags: optimization, profiling, anylogic

I recently hit a severe performance wall in an AnyLogic model and decided to do some method profiling. The top-level culprit was `com.anylogic.engine.Engine.mc()`, but what does it do, and how do we speed it up?

[image: Profiler Snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was explained to me that `com.anylogic.engine.Engine.mc()` is where conditions in events and transitions are checked. If `Engine.mc()` is slowing you down, check your condition events and condition transitions!

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, never use conditional transitions, only message-based, timeout-based and agent-arrival-based ones. Otherwise, your condition-based transition keeps checking all the time if it's condition has been met yet.

Comment: Agreed! That tends to be the optimization I use after I've clearly laid out my thoughts in a statechart. In the model that sparked this Q&A I hadn't noticed that I had left a conditional transition. I was really paying for it in execution speed and didn't want to see others get caught in the same trap. Hopefully our comments help others in the future!

Comment: Hi Dylan, didn't see you were the author (and respondent) :-)