# AnyLogic model run profile

Tags: anylogic

Is there any way to get time consumption profile of an AnyLogic model?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069863/what-is-engine-mc-and-why-is-it-slowing-down-my-model) from Dylan where he did some kind of method profiling : does it comes from an AnyLogic intern tool or from something external? How can I generate it for my model?

It would give me a first approach to understand the weak performance I get from my model but if something more precise exists (like in other discrete event simulation software) I would be happy to learn about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Dylan is using there is an application called VisualVM. You can download it here:
https://visualvm.github.io/

Depending on your operating system you can learn how to install it and run it here:
https://visualvm.github.io/gettingstarted.html

And when you run VisualVM, whenever you run a simulation experiment, it will immediately appear in the VisualVM panel automatically. It should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Another tool is **Java Mission Control**, which comes included with the Java Development Kit (JDK).

To start profiling you start your model but not yet run it. The Java thread of your model will apear in the JVM Browser. You right-click on it and select "Start Flight Recording" and choose how long you want the recording to be. Now you let your model run.

Once the recording is done, you can analyse the profile, which looks something like this:
[image: Java Mission Control Screenshot]